Connected component of affinoid perfectoid space
I'm reading Scholze's paper Etale cohomology of diamonds.


$\DeclareMathOperator\Spa{Spa}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$
In proposition 7.23, he claimed that $\pi_0(\Spa(R,R^+))=\pi_0(\Spec(R^+/\varpi))$. I'm trying to prove this.
The collection of open and closed subsets of $X=\Spa(R,R^+)$ is bijective to idempotent elements of $R^+$, and then it's bijective to the collection of open and closed subsets of $\Spec(R^+)$:

For $U\subset X$ open and closed, there is a function $e\in R^+=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}^+)$ defined by $e|_U=0,e|_{X-U}=1$.
Conversely, for $e\in R^+$ idempotent, the subset $U=\{e=0\}$ is open and closed: $U=\{|e|\leq|\pi|\}$ and $X-U=\{|\pi|\leq|e|\}$ are open.

Now for a spectral space, the connected component containing a point is the intersection of all open and closed subsets containing that point. It seems that $\pi_0(\Spa(R,R^+))$ should be identified with (a subset?) of $\pi_0(\Spec(R^+))$, rather than with $\pi_0(\Spec(R^+/\varpi))$.
Also, I tried to consider $\pi_0(\Spec(R^+/\varpi))$ by study the idempotent elements of $R^+/\varpi$, but I didn't find anything useful.

Because $R^+$ is $\varpi$-adically complete, the idempotents of $R^+$ and $R^+/\varpi$ are in bijection; see here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09XD
